# Find a random variable which is the function of X and U and has a moment generating function which is a definite integral

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

I'm self teaching probability and came across this interesting question:

Find  a random variable which is the function of X and U and which has the moment generating function:
$$\int_{0}^{1} M_X(tu) du $$

Here $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.

Would really appreciate

Comment: This looks incomplete. Presumably $M_X(t)$ is the moment generating function of $X$ so $E[e^{tX}]$.  I do not see $Y$. Are you allowed to specify $U$, for example as a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I clipped this from a 4 part question. I assume that Y isn't needed in this part, and U is exactly as you defined. Please can you help? @Henry

Comment: It would help others help you if you showed what you had tried already

Comment: Try product, sum etc of $X$ and $U$ (assuming with independence of $X$ and $U$). It is very easy.

Comment: I have edited the question based on above comments. I hope I didn't mess up.